# HTML CSS Styling table loaded from Excel file

Tags: html, css, excel

im having problem about the text overlapping the border.
i just use overflow:visible in my css

This is my HTML table.

[image]

How can i make it like this?

[image]

I just want to hide the border if the text overflows..

heres the code for the first 2 row:

```
<div id="GridWeb1_viewPanel10" style="height: 598px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    <table id="GridWeb1_viewTable10" class="GridWeb1_3" style="width:0%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width: 14.25pt;" id="GridWeb1_!0CD10">
            <col style="width: 14.25pt;" id="GridWeb1_!1CD10">
            <col style="width: 14.25pt;" id="GridWeb1_!2CD10">
            <col style="width: 14.25pt;" id="GridWeb1_!3CD10">
            <col style="width: 14.25pt;" id="GridWeb1_!4CD10">
            <col style="width: 138.75pt;" id="GridWeb1_!5CD10">
            <col style="width: 93.75pt;" id="GridWeb1_!6CD10">
            <col style="width: 0pt;" id="GridWeb1_!7CD10">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="GridWeb1_[d_row]9" style="height:12.75pt;">
                <td style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="GridWeb1_0#9" class="GridWeb1_26" protected="1" align="left" valign="top">
                    <span class="acwxc" style="height: 11.75pt; display: block; vertical-align: top; -moz-user-select: none;">Residents</span>
                </td>
                <td style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="GridWeb1_1#9" class="GridWeb1_27" protected="1" valign="top">
                    <span class="acwxc" style="height: 11.75pt; display: block; vertical-align: top; -moz-user-select: none;"></span>
                </td>
                <td style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="GridWeb1_2#9" class="GridWeb1_27" protected="1" valign="top">
                     <span class="acwxc" style="height: 11.75pt; display: block; vertical-align: top; -moz-user-select: none;"></span>
                </td>
                <td style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="GridWeb1_3#9" class="GridWeb1_27" protected="1" valign="top">
                     <span class="acwxc" style="height: 11.75pt; display: block; vertical-align: top; -moz-user-select: none;"></span>
                </td>
                <td style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="GridWeb1_4#9" class="GridWeb1_27" protected="1" valign="top">
                     <span class="acwxc" style="height: 11.75pt; display: block; vertical-align: top; -moz-user-select: none;"></span>
                </td>
                <td style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="GridWeb1_5#9" class="GridWeb1_28" protected="1" valign="bottom">
                     <span class="acwxc" style="height: 11.75pt; display: block; vertical-align: bottom; -moz-user-select: none;"></span>
                </td>
                <td title="140150000000100000" style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="GridWeb1_6#9" class="GridWeb1_27" protected="1" align="center" valign="middle">
                     <span class="acwxc" style="height: 11.75pt; display: block; vertical-align: middle; -moz-user-select: none;">140150000000100000</span>
                </td>
                <td style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="GridWeb1_7#9" class="GridWeb1_28" protected="1" valign="bottom">
                     <span class="acwxc" style="height: 11.75pt; display: block; vertical-align: bottom; -moz-user-select: none;"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="GridWeb1_[d_row]10" style="height:12.75pt;">
                <td title="1. " style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="GridWeb1_0#10" class="GridWeb1_27" protected="1" align="right" valign="top">
                     <span class="acwxc" style="height: 11.75pt; display: block; vertical-align: top; -moz-user-select: none;">1. </span>
                </td>
                <td title="Loans to Government " style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="GridWeb1_1#10" class="GridWeb1_27" protected="1" valign="top">
                     <span class="acwxc" style="height: 11.75pt; display: block; vertical-align: top; -moz-user-select: none;">Loans to Government </span>
                </td>
                <td title="<NULL>" style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="GridWeb1_2#10" class="GridWeb1_27" protected="1" valign="top">
                     <span class="acwxc" style="height: 11.75pt; display: block; vertical-align: top; -moz-user-select: none;"></span>
                </td>
                <td title="<NULL>" style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="GridWeb1_3#10" class="GridWeb1_27" protected="1" valign="top">
                     <span class="acwxc" style="height: 11.75pt; display: block; vertical-align: top; -moz-user-select: none;"></span>
                </td>
                <td title="<NULL>" style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="GridWeb1_4#10" class="GridWeb1_26" protected="1" valign="top">
                     <span class="acwxc" style="height: 11.75pt; display: block; vertical-align: top; -moz-user-select: none;"></span>
                </td>
                <td title="<NULL>" style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="GridWeb1_5#10" class="GridWeb1_28" protected="1" valign="bottom">
                    <span class="acwxc" style="height: 11.75pt; display: block; vertical-align: bottom; -moz-user-select: none;"></span>
                </td>
                <td title="140150000500120000" style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="GridWeb1_6#10" class="GridWeb1_27" protected="1" align="center" valign="middle">
                    <span class="acwxc" style="height: 11.75pt; display: block; vertical-align: middle; -moz-user-select: none;">140150000500120000</span>
                </td>
                <td style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="GridWeb1_7#10" class="GridWeb1_28" protected="1" valign="bottom">
                    <span class="acwxc" style="height: 11.75pt; display: block; vertical-align: bottom; -moz-user-select: none;"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and the only css for each span:

```
span.acwxc {
    height: 11.75pt; 
    display: block; 
    vertical-align: top; 
    -moz-user-select: none;
    overflow:visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Want to share some code? Showing images isn't going to help anyone to assist you.

Comment: It seems that you need `<td colspan="number"> `

Comment: Only if i could add colspan... but the table is generated from excel sheet style..

Comment: What tool is used to generate HTML from Excel? Which version of Excel is used?

Comment: im using Aspose GridWeb